# Голосовой чат

Tags: c++

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, как на c++ написать голосовой чат. Кто знает статьи или книги на данную тему. Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1):

[XMPP](http://xmpp.org) Вам в помощь. Есть [либа](http://code.google.com/p/qxmpp/) для [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[libjingle](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/) - библиотека - расширение для XMPP, на основе которой сделан Google Talk. Почти не документирована, но есть пара примеров использования. Плюс есть [документация](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/talk/libjingle/developer_guide.html) по самому Google Talk.